# Validation stored procedure for Replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactional-replication

Does anyone know of the correct stored procedure that validates the actual code in transactional replication?  I have a view that basically is a select * from table1.  I changed that view to select * from table2 in the publisher and there is an error in the replication monitor (as there should be) but when I run the sp "sp_publication_validation" it validates.

Comment: probably a good one for http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

sp_publication_validation does a row count and/or checksum check at the publisher and subscriber and compares the two results.  If they compare as the same, the article is considered "good" and if not, it's considered "bad".  Now, how does your view fit into your replication setup?  Do you have the view published as an article?  If so, what is the value for schema_option for it in sysarticles (at the publisher)?  Also, what error are you getting in the replication monitor?

Comment: The view is a seperate publication and the only article within that publication and since it is a view it is in sysschemaarticles.  The schema_option is set to the following: 1. Generates object creation script 2. Creates schemas not present on subscriber.  The error I am getting is "Invalid object name 'DatabaseName.dbo.TableName'. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 208)"  The reason for the error is that the database and the table named in the view are not on the subscriber.